# Set the legend in a plot to have the name of a column in bokeh

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, graph, bokeh

Here is my code below, how can I make the legend take the name of the column in rf.index[0].
Simply passing rf.index[0] to legend creates a legend of the categories rather than the actual name of the column.

```
p1.line(
    x = 'x',
    y = rf.index[0],
    source=source,
    legend = ???,
    color = 'black'
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer!

```
legend = dict(value=rf.index[0])
```

source

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5365